# HTC One Camera photos have "pink background"

Tags: camera, htc-one

I am an active user of Android device, and I purchased a HTC One. In the advertisement they showed that this device has an Ultra Pixels camera, and you can click pictures in the low light with the best quality. But its just disappointing, when I click the pictures it comes with "Pinkish background". So can you please help me find out if this issue is with the software or with the camera itself. And if this issue is with the software will a fix be released or not?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a software issue, it is a hardware issue. Most of the times, they are referred as *pink spots* or *purple tint/haze*

It happens because apparently the component called ZOE puts a lot of strain on the camera module, which causes it to heat, and it could even lead to burning down your motherboard (in extreme cases).

Reference: http://forums.androidcentral.com/htc-one/351874-htc-one-heres-skinny-infamous-purple-tint-thermal-defect.html

Better call HTC for a replacement/Fix before your Warranty runs out.